# ActivatedRoute params not working in unit test when writing more than one test case

Tags: angular, testing

I'm mocking the params value of ActivatedRoute using the following code:

```
 providers: [
    {
      provide: ActivatedRoute,
      useValue: { params: of({id: 1})}
    },
```

My component uses the ActivateRoute as this:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.selectedId = +params['id'];
```

My testCases are currently empty.
The first one succeeds, the second one fails.

```
describe('The VIS form', () => {
  it('should be invalid', () => {
   //Nothing here
  });

  it('should be valid', () => {
   //Nothing here
  });
});
```

It's giving me the following error ONLY at the should be valid test case. the should be invalid test case works as expected:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber.route.params.subscribe.
```

I've tried mocking the ActivatedRoute using a stub, using a subject as a source for Params.

I expect both tests to pass, since they're both empty and do nothing.

[See image for the test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVO2B.png)

Comment: Probably has to do with https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10788. Try with `useFactory: () => { params: of({id: 1})}`

Comment: Using this factory does not fix it for me unfortunately.  

It does seem to move the errormessage from at safeSubscriber.params.subscribe to at ReviewCustomerComponent.ngOnInit. But it still displays the same error message

Comment: You should post a complete minimal example that we can use to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `useValue` doesn't work but I usually use a class to do this:

```
  class MockActivatedRoute {
    params = of({
        id: '1'
    });
  }
```

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: ActivatedRoute,
      useClass: MockActivatedRoute
    },
```

Does that make any difference ?